# Coherence factor in Delay-And-Sum-Beamformer: Triangle Inequality

Tags: matlab, ultrasound, imageprocessing

I'm writing a delay-and-sum-beamformer in MATLAB that incorporates a so-called and widely used coherence factor `CF`. Now I'm confused about the math behind that factor!

Given a vector `signal` of length `N` consisting of positive and negative real numbers (I will use MATLAB style):

- One paper claims that: `CF1 = sum(signal)^2/sum(signal.^2) <= 1`
- Another paper claims: `CF2 = sum(signal)^2/sum(signal.^2)/N <= 1`

The first statement does not hold i.e. for `signal = [2 -5 -4]` because `CF1 = 49/45`!

Is the second statement right? Why? I looked the triangle inequality up, but unfortunately I could not learn anything from it.

Comment: I hate to redirect you again, but this might be a better fit for [DSP](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks! I'll take my tour through the stack-ecosystem :)

Comment: Are you asking what the correct formula for 'Coherence Factor' is? Or are you asking for a proof (using triangle inequality) that the CF is <=1 ? Wherever this question is posted, please provide reference or quotation from the two papers. But it is pretty clear the first equation is wrong. Probably a typo.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what CF is. But:

Just looking at it, the first equation looks wrong. It depends on N. The second equation looks like 'the average of the signal, squared, divided by the average of the signal squared.'

It looks less funny, with the N gone, if you first take the average, then the average of the squares, then compute average^2/avgsqrs.

Also, it is not clear what your second equation means. It should be:

$$
sum(signal)^2/(N*sum(signal^2))
$$

Comment: see http://www.ultrasound.bme.utexas.edu/papers/Park_IEEEproc_2008.pdf equation 6